# Are Australian Federal Senators Bob Carr and Kim Carr related, or do they just have the same surname by coincidence?

Tags: australia, alp

I've tried to Google this question, but I haven't been able to find anything relevant, which suggests that it is just a coincidence, but I would have thought that surely someone else would be curious about this.

Comment: They certainly don't look at all similar!

Comment: After reviewing the Wikipedia pages of both Carrs, I can find no reference to either of them.  Whilst this doesn't mean that they aren't related, it strongly suggests it (hence, why I'm posting this as a comment rather than answer)

Comment: In my personal opinion it would depend on whether either of them can be rooted back to County Sligo, Ireland?

Comment: Of course, if you go back enough generations, everyone is related. The real question is how many generations back you have to go and whether that number is small enough to care about. The odds that they are related in some way going back 10 generations (about 300 years) for two white people of a certain social class with the same last name in Australia is very high, particularly if you count relationships by marriage. But, usually relations that are more remote than two or three generations are not considered very significant.

Answer (score 4):

**No, that are most likely not related.**

The most recent edition of [*Parliamentary relations: political families in the Commonwealth Parliament*](http://www.aph.gov.au/About_Parliament/Parliamentary_Departments/Parliamentary_Library/pubs/rp/rp1516/ParlRel), produced by the Parliamentary Library does not have them listed as relatives.